# Rewrite rule visibility possible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache RewriteRule in my .htaccess as shown below. Is there any possibility to see the redirecting target for an outstanding developer?

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.xml folder-s8292B/script.php?parameter=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

I've inspect it in my browser development console and I can't see anything of this rewrite.
Is there any way to reveal the target destination of this file with external tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the rewriting is done internally to Apache and is not seen from outside.

If you want for the rewrite to be visible, you can activate de redirection flag, like this (note the `R` added):

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.xml folder-s8292B/script.php?parameter=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R,L]
```

You can also customize the HTTP code with the syntax `R=xxx` (with `xxx` being equals to 300 to 399).

More information on Apache doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html